# What is the best way to uninstall nginx

Tags: nginx

I'm trying to add new module to nginx with naxsi, but I should reinstall nginx. What is the better way of removing nginx?

Answer (score 432, accepted):

**Removes all but config files.**

```
sudo apt-get remove nginx nginx-common
```

**Removes everything.**

```
sudo apt-get purge nginx nginx-common
```

After using any of the above commands, use this in order to remove dependencies used by nginx which are no longer required.

```
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

Comment: `rm -rf /etc/nginx` to remove the conf files too.

Comment: @scarver2 This is old, but that's what `apt-get purge` does.

Comment: Try also `sudo apt-get purge nginx-common`

Comment: With Ubuntu 14.04, it's now: `sudo apt-get remove nginx-full nginx-common`

Comment: also remove your ppa archive if you have some in you /etc/apt/source.list

Comment: So there are different packages of nginx : nginx, nginx-full and nginx-common. Right?

Comment: `nginx-core` needs to be removed too

Comment: This answer helped me to remove ngnix from ec2 [this](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/deployment-guides/amazon-ec2-instances-for-nginx/) is how it was installed with ansible.

Comment: also disable startup script on boot: `sudo systemctl disable nginx`

Comment: Try `sudo apt purge nginx nginx-common nginx-core ; sudo apt autoremove`

Answer (score 13):

Uninstall everything and install once again

```
sudo apt remove --purge nginx*
sudo apt autoremove
sudo apt update
sudo apt install nginx
```

Enjoy