# Nginx after update doesn't work anymore on ubuntu 18.04.1

Tags: apt, dpkg, nginx

After the nginx update the other day I can't start it any more. Even if I reinstall it through `apt-get purge nginx-full -y && apt-get autoremove -y && apt-get install nginx-full` it doesn't start at all.
This is the messeage I got when I run the command above:
https://pastebin.com/Sus4CdFY (cause anti-spam i need to outsource)

and when I run this `systemctl status nginx.service` I get this:

```
● nginx.service - A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/nginx.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Mon 2020-01-20 19:12:50 CET; 3min 7s ago
     Docs: man:nginx(8)
 Main PID: 13451 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Jan 20 19:12:50 myServer systemd[1]: Starting A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server...
Jan 20 19:12:50 myServer nginx[7110]: nginx: [emerg] dlopen() "/usr/share/nginx/modules/ngx_http_auth_pam_module.so" failed (/usr/share/nginx/modules/ngx_http_auth_pam_module.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory) in /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/50-mod-http-auth-pam.conf:1
Jan 20 19:12:50 myServer nginx[7110]: nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed
Jan 20 19:12:50 myServer systemd[1]: nginx.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1
Jan 20 19:12:50 myServer systemd[1]: nginx.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Jan 20 19:12:50 myServer systemd[1]: Failed to start A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server.
```

I am using Plesk with apache2 and nginx. Just to mention it, already visted the following post:
[Nginx installation error in Ubuntu 16.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/764222/nginx-installation-error-in-ubuntu-16-04)
[What is the best way to uninstall nginx](https://askubuntu.com/questions/235347/what-is-the-best-way-to-uninstall-nginx)
[How to fix the nginx package?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/670474/how-to-fix-the-nginx-package)

[dpkg-deb: error: paste subprocess was killed by signal (Broken pipe)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1062171/dpkg-deb-error-paste-subprocess-was-killed-by-signal-broken-pipe/1062184) (I used this to update nginx, i replaced the nvidia line with `nginx-core_1.14.0-0ubuntu1.7_amd64.deb`)

I hope some of you nice gentleman or gentlewoman could help me.

Comment: Which NGINX did you have before you installed `nginx-core` and are you using any odd repositories?  Because the `.so` won't be present unless that corresponding library is available, and in 16.04 (1.14.x) it won't be.

Comment: nginx version 1.12.0-0ubuntu1.6 ( I think, not sure)
I added the reposetory manual in ´/etc/apt/sources.list.d/nginx.list´
`deb [arch=amd64] http://nginx.org/packages/mainline/ubuntu/ bionic nginx
deb-src http://nginx.org/packages/mainline/ubuntu/ bionic nginx
`  I Hope this is what you mean.

Comment: `nginx-core` is NOT the proper version of nginx to install in this case, you'll need to do `sudo apt-get remove nginx-core && sudo apt-get install nginx-full` to restore the nginx.org version of the packages.  nginx-core is actually *older* than the version on nginx.org and will cause conflicts.

Comment: @ThomasWard thats what i got after the command https://pastebin.com/LyY8xcVu